# Can I apply a vectorized function to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, vectorization

I am pretty new to `pandas` and `numpy`, and I'm trying to figure out the best way to do some things.

Right now I am trying to call a function on every row of a `dataframe`. If I pass in three `numpy` arrays to this function, it's very fast, but using `apply` on the `dataframe` is very slow.

My guess is that `numpy` is using vectorized functions in the first case, and not in the second. Is there a way to get `pandas` to use that optimization? Basically, in pseudocode I think `apply` is doing something like `for row in frame: func(row['a'], row['b'], row['c'])` but I want it to do `func(col['a'], col['b'], col['c'])`.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import beta

count = 100000

# If I start with a given dataframe and use apply, it's very slow

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=(count, 3)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df.apply(lambda frame: beta.cdf(frame['a'], frame['b'], frame['c']), axis=1)

# However, if I split out each column into a numpy array, this is very fast.

a = df['a'].as_matrix()
b = df['b'].as_matrix()
c = df['c'].as_matrix()

beta.cdf(a, b, c)

# But at this point I've lost the context of the dataframe.
# I would like to keep the results in a new column for further processing
```

Comment: Vectorization would be function specific. So, are you trying to vectorize just that `beta.cdf` or could there be others?

Comment: So beta.cdf already accepts arrays (and Series) why do you use apply instead of that?

Comment: Why not just call `beta.cdf(df.a, df.b, df.c)`?

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's unclear. I'm starting with a `dataframe`. So I'd need to extract the columns into `numpy` arrays in order to call `beta.cdf` directly. Which I can do, but that loses all other context from the dataframe. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: You don't need to convert them to numpy arrays.  See my previous comment.  You can just do `beta.cdf(df.a, df.b, df.c)`.

Comment: @BrenBarn Ah, I see now. I didn't realize I could do that. I feel sort of dumb. You can post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not clear why you're trying to use `apply`.  You can just do `beta.cdf(df.a, df.b, df.c)`.

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't realize I could just pass in `dataframe` columns into a vectorized function.

Comment: Sure you can! Recall each column in a pandas dataframe is a pandas series.